# Is there any way to cache ASIFormDataRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I'm using ASIFormDataRequest for Post data then parsing with JSON.  ASIHTTPRequest has built in caching using `[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];`.  Does anyone know if there is anything similar for ASIFormDataRequest?

Example:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myapp/20110715/60b88126/load_dr_daily_schedule/%@/", [self getHost], [dateFormat stringFromDate:today]]];

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
        [self addCurrentUserLoginToPostRequest:request];        
        [request setPostValue:[dateFormat stringFromDate:today] forKey:@"target_date"];

        [request startSynchronous];

        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSString *responseString;
        if (!error) {
            responseString = [request responseString];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
        return [responseString JSONValue];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIFormDataRequest is a subclass of ASIHTTPRequest, so it was the same properties as ASIHTTPRequest.

Note that it won't cache POST requests though.

Comment: I updated question with 2 examples of code that I am using in my app.  Can I cache this?  It has a `getPost` in it.

Comment: The code is ASIHTTPRequest will not cache that, as it's a POST request I believe. Only you can answer whether you can safely cache it or not; I don't understand your use case. If it is safe to cache it, you just need to alter the ASIHTTPRequest code so that it caches it in a way that's appropriate to your use case.

Comment: What do you mean alter it? Alter the ASIHTTPRequest API?

Comment: Alter the code; implement a new cache delegate (you can base it on the existing one), and it's possible you might need to make some very small tweaks to the existing ASIHTTPRequest code too.